# Scrollbars on frame using page tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page, scrollbars

I'm working on a Facebook Page Tab app. 
Can someone tell me how to get rid of the inner scrollbars?

My app looks like this: http://imageshack.us/f/39/52017175.jpg/ but it should look like this: http://imageshack.us/f/805/84116468.jpg/ . (notice that the second page scroller is on the right, not in the frame).

I tried changing the settings but that doesn't work...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it out:

Apparently, FB made some changes again.
Adding this did the trick for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
    {
        FB.init({ appId: '',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true});

        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    }
        </script>
```

Don't forget to load the .js-file, off course.
Next, make sure your css-file blocks any scrollbars (overflow: hidden).